# Iphone Undocumented/Private API vs. Toolchain

Tags: iphone

Excuse me if this is a "sparse" question but, I'm somehow confused wit the terms of "Undocumented API call" and "Toolchain" (of Saurik).

Are they same? Or toolchain is "yet another wrapper" for Undoc. APIs? Or entirely different things?

And what place does Erica Sadun's work sit in these definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, "toolchain" refers to the unofficial iphone sdk and compiling tools, the ones you use to code applications that typically run on jailbroken iphones.

About Erica Sadun's work, I don't think there is a general answer as she published applications for toolchain but her book targets the official sdk.

Comment: So is it possible to build applications using private apis, without toolchain, and publish them on cydia sources?

Comment: @paul I think you can, see http://wikee.iphwn.org/howto:using_sdk_with_toolchain_headers but it has been a long time since I've coded for the iPhone

Comment: Yes, you can build using Apple's SDK, reference private APIs, and publish them on Cydia (it's just a set of binaries after all).  For Cydia you can publish anything.  How you make it run is up to you.

Comment: One thing to note is that Erica Sadun's book includes many examples of using private APIs, even with the official iPhone SDK.